# How to sketch the locus of $0<\arg{\frac{z-1}{z+1}}< \frac{\pi}{4}$ ??

Tags: complex-analysis

I know how to find the locus where the same expression is equal to an angle,but I don't understand how to sketch it where the same expression is between to other angles.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what $\arg(z)$ is?

Answer (score 1):

Had they asked you locus of $arg\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ then your figure is **correct** which is any point on circumferance of  a circle with centre (0,1) and radius $\sqrt{2}\ $ i.e, $x^2+y^2-2y-1=0$

**now, coming to your question** :

**discussion for upper inequality** i.e,  $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

this inequality wants you to move your **triangle** formed between **any point outside** this  circle that you've drawn  (because you want angle less than $45 ^{\circ}$ degree so you must have to go outside the circle) and $-1$, $1$ **anywhere** in the complex plane

**discussion for lower inequality** i.e, **0**

now the lower limit put constraint that you must move only in the upper half plane

i.e,$ Im z>0$

combining above two results

**the locus of your inequality is a triangle formed between any point outside this  circle that you've drawn and $-1$ and $1$ such that you move only in upper half plane**  (in any direction counterclokwise or clockwise )

Comment: Hi thanks for answering back.But what would happen if we had another exercise with different inequality such as: pi/6<=arg{z-2i/z+2i}<=pi/4,which will be the locus of this inequality?

Comment: @FrancRibaj: in this case locus will be intersection of  $\mathbf {interior}\  $ region of circle $  x^2+y^2+4 \sqrt {3} x-4=0 $ and  $\mathbf {exterior}$ region of circle $ x^2+y^2+4x-4=0$

Answer (score 0):

let $z=x+iy$ and define the complex number $w\equiv\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ then we can split $w$ into real and imaginary parts by multiplying numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator.

$$w = \frac{(x+1)+iy}{(x-1)+iy} 
\\=\frac{((x+1)+iy)((x-1)-iy)}{(x-1)^2+y^2} 
\\=\frac{ (x^2-1+y^2)+i(-2y)}{(x-1)^2+y^2} $$

The region described by $0< \arg(w)<\frac \pi 4$
Is the region in the first quadrant between the x axis and the line $y=x$

In terms of real and imaginary parts, this can be described as ...
$$ Re(w)>0 
\\Im(w)>0
\\ Re(w)>Im(w) $$

Notice that the denominator of the expression for $w$ is never negative (it is equal to zero at $(1,0)$ but $w$ is not defined there so cannot satisfy any inequality.)

This means that 
$$ Re(w)>0 \implies x^2+y^2-1 > 0
\\Im(w)>0 \implies -2y>0
\\ Re(w)>Im(w) \implies x^2+y^2-1>-2y 
\\ \implies x^2+y^2+2y-1>0 
\\ \implies x^2+(y+1)^2>2 $$
So the region you are looking for is the part of the lower half plane that is outside both the circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+(y+1)^2=2$.

The way those circles intersect means that this is equivalent to the part of the lower half plane that is outside the circle  $x^2+(y+1)^2=2$.

Comment: Could you explain me again why Re(w)>0,Im(w)>0 =>Re(w)>Im(w)??

Comment: The locus of points satisfying $\arg(z)=\theta$ is just the line $y=x \tan\theta$ and $\tan(\frac \pi 4) =1$

Comment: $Re(w)>0$ and $Im(w)>0$ puts $w$ in the first quadrant
$Re(w)>Im(w)$ ensures that $w$ lies below the line $y=x$